# Python Multiprocessing Increasing Time delay using pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-3.3, pool

I have to solve a complex network optimization problem using a heuristic algorithm (e.g. ant algorithm). This algorithm is decomposed in two steps: 1.) Calculate new solutions using an random component, 2.) Evaluate new Solutions. These two parts are very highly time-consuming and solved the problem parallel using multiprocessing in subprograms. With increasing number of iteration the time duration of the steps increases very fast. I localized the time delay between the initialization of the parallel processes (labels `timeMainCalculate` and `timeMainEvaluate`) and the start of the first subprogram (labels `timeSubCalculate` and `timeSubEvaluate`). In the first iteration the time difference `timeMainCalculate-timeSubCalculate` respectively `timeMainEvaluate-timeSubEvaluate` is nearly 0, after 100 iterations it is about 10 seconds for both steps and after 200 steps the time difference is about 20. This time difference is linear increasing. The time duration for calculation and evaluation in the subprograms is constant. So it might be a problem in the communication between the main program and the subprograms using `multiprocessing. Pool`.

For your Information: I’m using Python 3.3 on a eight core computer.

**opt_heuristic.py:**

```
import multiprocessing.Pool
import datetime
import calculate, evaluate

epsilon = 1e-10
nbOfCpusForParallel = 6
nbCalculation = 6

def calculate_bound_update_information(result):
    Do_some_calculation using result
    return [bound,x,y,z]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Inititalize x,y,z
    while bound > epsilon:

        # Calculate new Solution
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=nbOfCpusForParallel)
        result_parallel = list()
        for i in range(nbCalculation):
            result_parallel.append(pool.apply_async(calculate.main,[x,y,z]))
        timeMainCalculate = datetime.datetime.now() 
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        resultCalculation = [result_parallel[i].get() for i in range(nbCalculation)]

        # Evaluate Solutions
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=nbOfCpusForParallel)
        argsEvalute = [[resultCalculation[i][0],resultCalculation[i][1]] for i in range(len(resultCalculation))]
        result_evaluate = list()
        for i in range(len(resultCalculation)):
            result_evaluate.append(pool.apply_async(evaluate.main,argsEvalute[i]))
        timeMainEvaluate = datetime.datetime.now()
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        resultEvaluation = [result_evaluate[i].get() for i in range(len(resultCalculation))]
        [bound,x,y,z] = calculate_bound_update_information(resultEvaluation)
```

**calculate.py:**

```
import datetime
def main(x,y,z):
    timeSubCalculate = datetime.datetime.now() 
    Do some random calculation using x,y,z
    return result
```

**evaluate.py**

```
import datetime
def main(x,y):
    timeSubEvaluate = datetime.datetime.now() 
    Do some evaluation using x,y
    return result
```

I seems to me that the main program store some information of the parallel process. I tried some things like delete the pool variable but it was not successful.

Has somebody an idea what's the technical problem and how it could be solved? Thanks.

Comment: Are you passing larger amounts of data between processes with each iteration? IPC is expensive - it can't take quite a while to pass large objects from parent to child.

Comment: If this linux, globals are still valid after a fork and can be used by the child processes. You can put x,y,z into a list in the module globals and just pass their index on apply_async. Same for evaluate, just make sure that you create the pool after you calculate it.

Comment: @dano: No. In each iteration I pass new information for the calculation which have always the same structure and size. So the amount of data in each iteration is constant.

Comment: @tdelaney: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately I'am working on Windows.